# Why it gives different address with same variable?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

The both line of `printf` should print the address of variable ,right?
but they both give different value...
Why it so , both  should give same value coz memory location allocated to variable `a` is fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int *ptra = &a;
    printf("%d", &a);
    printf("%p", ptra);
}
```

Comment: Use `%p` for both printfs and you should get the correct result.

Comment: Printing a pointer using `%d` is undefined behavior. In other words: It may print any value. **Always use `%p` for pointers**

Comment: @4386427 And always cast the pointer value to `void*`. `%p` specifically requires a `void*` argument, not a pointer of any type.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the output of your program on my system:

```
-12115289320x7ffeb7c9891c
```

The two outputs are jammed together on one line, making it difficult to tell which is which.

Adding newlines to the output, I get:

```
344225740
0x7ffc148477cc
```

(There's no guarantee that a variable will have the same address from one run of a program to the next, and some systems deliberately change memory allocations.)

The `%d` format specifier requires an argument of type `int`. The correct format specifier for a pointer value is `%p`, and it requires an argument of type `void*`. Using inconsistent types, as you've done in your program, causes *undefined behavior*. At best, on many systems pointers are 64 bits and `int` is 32 bits, so `%d` can't possibly show an entire pointer value. It *might* show part of the pointer value, it might show garbage, or it might crash.

The `%p` format typically uses hexadecimal, but the format is implementation-defined.

Here's a corrected version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int *ptra = &a;
    printf("%p\n", (void*)&a);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)ptra);
}
```

and the output on my system:

```
0x7ffd62a733ec
0x7ffd62a733ec
```

You'll see different output, but the two lines should match each other.

Note: `void main()` is incorrect; the correct declaration is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same number. You're printing one in decimal form, the other in hexadecimal form.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a=5;
    int *ptra=&a;
    printf("%p\r\n",&a);
    printf("%p\r\n",ptra);
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
0x7ffc8e4cb974
0x7ffc8e4cb974
```

for me

Comment: The `\r` is unnecessary. If you're on a system that uses CR-LF line endings, a simple `\n` will be translated as needed. If you're on a system that uses just LF, the `\r` is incorrect.

Comment: printing pointers with `%d` is UB

Comment: updated the code to remove `%d`

Answer (score 0):

Using `%d` escape sequence in your first `printf` is converting your reference from hexadecimal to decimal, i.e, (x)<sub>16</sub> --> (x)<sub>10</sub>.

So your code should be:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a=5;
    int *ptra=&a;
    printf("%p\n",&a);
    printf("%p",ptra);
    return 0;
 }
```

Output: (may vary on your machine)

```
000000000061fe14
000000000061fe14
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the difference in format strings.

```
%d    takes 32 bits and displays it as a signed value  123
%p    takes a pointer and display it in address format    0fef:0004
```

Actual value is same but there is difference of interpreting the value.

Comment: `%d` processes an `int` — these days, outside of embedded systems, an `int` is usually 32-bits, not 16-bits (though that is officially a possibility).  And the address format you show is unusual but not wrong — what `%p` produces is implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks for input I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the answer from Keith Thompson (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70982344/4386427) the reason is that you are printing an integer value by using `%d` but the argument isn't an integer - it is a pointer value. Providing an argument with a type that doesn't match the format specifier (i.e. providing a pointer value for `%d`) leads to undefined behavior which means that it may print any value, text or even nothing.

All that is already well covered by Keith Thompson (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70982344/4386427)

I just like to add that in case you actually want to print a decimal integer representation of the pointer value, you can use the types `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <inttypes.h> 
int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int *ptra = &a;
    printf("%p\n", (void*)&a);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)ptra);
    
    intptr_t dptr = (intptr_t)(void*)ptra;
    uintptr_t uptr = (uintptr_t)(void*)ptra;

    printf("A signed integer representation of the same pointer in decimal        : %" PRIdPTR "\n", dptr);
    printf("An unsigned integer representation of the same pointer in decimal     : %" PRIuPTR "\n", uptr);
    printf("An unsigned integer representation of the same pointer in hexadecimal : %" PRIxPTR "\n", uptr);

}
```

Possible output:

```
0x7ffcaceba19c
0x7ffcaceba19c
A signed integer representation of the same pointer in decimal        : 140723209609628
An unsigned integer representation of the same pointer in decimal     : 140723209609628
An unsigned integer representation of the same pointer in hexadecimal : 7ffcaceba19c
```